# Spring Pulsar listener does not receive messages

Tags: datastax, apache-pulsar, spring-pulsar

**Edit**: the issue was that my `@PulsarListener` was in a class that was not a Spring Bean, and as such did not get discovered. Adding a `@Service` annotation solved the problem.

I'm in a Spring Boot 3.0.1 project and using version 0.1.1-SNAPSHOT of `org.springframework.pulsar:spring-pulsar-spring-boot-starter`.

I'm on a arm64 Mac, but I'm running a x86 JDK (19.0.2-amzn) because conscrypt does not support arm64 yet.

I am able to publish messages successfully, but I'm not receiving any messages.

There are no exceptions in the log unless I turn on `debug` logging for `org.apache.pulsar`. With debug logging, I get the following exceptions:

```
ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pulsar.shade.org.apache.pulsar.policies.data.loadbalancer.LoadManagerReport
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:121) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:1069) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:1135) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:1118) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.common.util.ObjectMapperFactory.setAnnotationsModule(ObjectMapperFactory.java:203) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.common.util.ObjectMapperFactory.create(ObjectMapperFactory.java:117) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.springframework.pulsar.autoconfigure.AuthParameterUtils.maybeConvertToEncodedParamString(AuthParameterUtils.java:65) ~[spring-pulsar-spring-boot-autoconfigure-0.1.1-20230128.101302-74.jar:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.PropertyMapper$Source.lambda$as$2(PropertyMapper.java:197) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.PropertyMapper$Source.to(PropertyMapper.java:291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.pulsar.autoconfigure.PulsarProperties$Client.buildProperties(PulsarProperties.java:1616) ~[spring-pulsar-spring-boot-autoconfigure-0.1.1-20230128.101302-74.jar:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.pulsar.autoconfigure.PulsarProperties.buildClientProperties(PulsarProperties.java:113) ~[spring-pulsar-spring-boot-autoconfigure-0.1.1-20230128.101302-74.jar:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.pulsar.autoconfigure.PulsarAutoConfiguration.pulsarClientConfiguration(PulsarAutoConfiguration.java:75) ~[spring-pulsar-spring-boot-autoconfigure-0.1.1-20230128.101302-74.jar:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:491) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    [...]
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_osx_x86_64, netty_tcnative_x86_64, netty_tcnative]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:114) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:705) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:146) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:124) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultClientProvider(SslContext.java:120) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:817) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:611) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.common.util.SecurityUtility.createNettySslContextForClient(SecurityUtility.java:303) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.common.util.SecurityUtility.createNettySslContextForClient(SecurityUtility.java:287) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.common.util.SecurityUtility.createNettySslContextForClient(SecurityUtility.java:211) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PulsarChannelInitializer.lambda$new$0(PulsarChannelInitializer.java:122) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.util.ObjectCache.get(ObjectCache.java:48) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PulsarChannelInitializer.lambda$initTls$1(PulsarChannelInitializer.java:171) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: org_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative_osx_x86_64
        at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:239) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:105) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/liborg_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative_osx_x86_64.jnilib
        at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:181)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no org_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative_osx_x86_64 in java.library.path: /Users/mhellber/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2444)
            at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
            at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2047)
            at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
            at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:391)
            at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
            ... 21 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no org_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative_osx_x86_64 in java.library.path: /Users/mhellber/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2444)
                at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
                at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2047)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:425)
                at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:417)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:383)
                ... 22 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: org_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative_x86_64
        at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:239) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:105) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/liborg_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative_x86_64.jnilib
        at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:181)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no org_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative_x86_64 in java.library.path: /Users/mhellber/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2444)
            at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
            at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2047)
            at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
            at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:391)
            at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
            ... 21 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no org_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative_x86_64 in java.library.path: /Users/mhellber/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2444)
                at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
                at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2047)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:425)
                at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:417)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:383)
                ... 22 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: org_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative
        at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:239) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:105) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/liborg_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative.jnilib
        at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:181)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no org_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative in java.library.path: /Users/mhellber/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2444)
            at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
            at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2047)
            at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
            at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:391)
            at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
            ... 21 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no org_apache_pulsar_shade_netty_tcnative in java.library.path: /Users/mhellber/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2444)
                at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
                at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2047)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:425)
                at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:417)
                at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:383)
                ... 22 common frames omitted
```

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'int org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.internal.tcnative.Library.aprMajorVersion()'
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.internal.tcnative.Library.aprMajorVersion(Native Method) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.internal.tcnative.Library.initialize(Library.java:191) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.initializeTcNative(OpenSsl.java:710) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:163) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:124) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultClientProvider(SslContext.java:120) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:817) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:611) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.common.util.SecurityUtility.createNettySslContextForClient(SecurityUtility.java:303) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.common.util.SecurityUtility.createNettySslContextForClient(SecurityUtility.java:287) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.common.util.SecurityUtility.createNettySslContextForClient(SecurityUtility.java:211) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PulsarChannelInitializer.lambda$new$0(PulsarChannelInitializer.java:122) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.util.ObjectCache.get(ObjectCache.java:48) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PulsarChannelInitializer.lambda$initTls$1(PulsarChannelInitializer.java:171) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[pulsar-client-all-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

I tried adding `netty-tcnative` as a dependency in my `pom.xml`, but it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

All of these exceptions are red herrings - when level is `DEBUG` this is expected from Pulsar.

The `netty-tcnative` logs - this is just part of its load process. It can't find it so security defaults to JDK provider. Note the `DEBUG` level of the following statement:

```
2023-01-28T20:47:16.894-06:00 DEBUG 19255 --- [r-client-io-1-1] o.a.p.s.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl     : Failed to load netty-tcnative; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable, unless the application has already loaded the symbols by some other means. See https://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html for more information.
```

And the `CNFEX` is in the pulsar code and expected (see [ObjectMapperFactory](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/pulsar-common/src/main/java/org/apache/pulsar/common/util/ObjectMapperFactory.java#L270).

I created a sample app that sends and receives using:

- SpringBoot 3.0.2
- Java 19 (x86 JDK (19.0.2-amzn)
- Spring Pulsar 0.1.1-SNAPSHOT

There is something else going on w/ your app. Turn apache logging back to ERROR and try this simple app:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TcnativeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TcnativeApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner1(PulsarTemplate<String> pulsarTemplate) {
        String topic1 = "your-topic-goes-here";
        return args -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                pulsarTemplate.send(topic1, "This is message " + (i + 1));
            }
        };
    }

    @PulsarListener(subscriptionName = "subscription-1", topics = "your-topic-goes-here")
    void listen1(String message) {
        System.out.println("***** " + message);
    }
}
```

About the `@PulsarListener` needing to be a `@Service`... ultimately the framework uses a Spring BeanPostProcessor([PulsarListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-pulsar/blob/82e055a4bce81ac48da7de5bd7889b43b5e280dc/spring-pulsar/src/main/java/org/springframework/pulsar/annotation/PulsarListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L223)) and any beans in the app context that are marked w/ `@PulsarListener` are processed accordingly. So `@Bean`, `@Service` or `@Component` are common ways to do that. The most common is to put the listener as a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class.

Comment: This inspired a newly added [Troubleshooting wiki]( https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-pulsar/wiki/Troubleshooting#pulsar-exceptions-in-startup-logs)

Comment: They were indeed red herrings. My problem was much simpler (and dumber): the class in which I had the listener was not annotated with `@Service`/`@Component` and as such didn't get picked up. I will update my question.

Comment: Glad you got squared away @MarcusHellberg. I updated my answer - added a blurb at the end of the original answer. I think the original answer is worth leaving as-is for people running into this later.